# Mysql update column replacing part of text

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I'm really new with sql and I'm having some troubles with the following task:
I have a column with text values which represent numbers. The scales of these numbers is different so that some are thousands (e.g. 32.11k) while others are millions (e.g  5.40M). I would like to transform them into numbers in thousands so that 32.11k would become 32.11 and 5.40M would become 5400.

I thought this might have worked for thousands but it doesn't.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, 'k', '')
```

I've also tried the following with wildcards (for millions) but I guess I must be doing something wrong.

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name,'.%M','.%')
WHERE column_name LIKE '%.%M'
```

Comment: That doesn't work for thousands? It sure looks like it should.

Comment: There are only thousands and millions, in case of millions found multiply by 1000.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = CAST(CASE WHEN col LIKE '%k' THEN CAST(REPLACE(col, 'k', '') AS DECIMAL(10,2))
                    WHEN col LIKE '%M'
                    THEN ROUND(1000*CAST(REPLACE(col, 'M', '') AS DECIMAL(10,2)), 2)
               END AS CHAR)
WHERE col LIKE '%k' OR col LIKE '%M'
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: @HartCO We both still have problems...fixing now

Comment: Why `CAST()` when it's a string field?

Comment: @HartCO `column_name` is a `varchar` column (presumably), which means we must update using text as well.  To deal with millions, we first have to convert to `decimal`, then multiply by 1000, then convert back to text.

Answer (score 1):

Your `k` update looks like it should work, you can do them both in one `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = CASE WHEN column_name LIKE '%k%' THEN REPLACE(column_name, 'k', '') 
                       WHEN column_name LIKE '%M%' THEN REPLACE(column_name,'M','')*1000 
                  END
WHERE column_name LIKE '%k%' OR column_name LIKE '%M%'
```

Comment: Your query appears to work fine on MySQL ([Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fee9e/9)), but would fail on other RDBMS such as SQL Server which do not support implicit type conversions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True, I trusted the mysql tag and didn't worry about that, but good point.

Comment: Upvoted for being the simplest option when using MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm actually using MySQL but this query doesn't return the expected results.  Nothing changes. Any suggestion?

Comment: @MattJay That's odd, do you know what version of MySQL you're using?

Comment: @Hart version 5.7.17

Comment: @MattJay Thanks, I had `column_name` in the `CASE` expression but `col` in the `WHERE` so needed to be updated, I assume that was the reason it didn't do anything, but I only tested on 5.6.